# Ext.form.TextField: getValue() works but setValue(...) does not... why?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm creating a text field as follows

```
new Ext.form.TextField({
  id: 'valueTxt',
  xtype: 'textfield',
  width: 170,
  height: 35,
  style: {'margin': '5px 5px 0px 5px'}
})
```

after that

```
alert(Ext.get('valueTxt').getValue());
```

is OK. But

```
 Ext.get('valueTxt').setValue('hello');
```

says that `Ext.get('valueTxt').setValue` is undefined.

Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Ext.get() return Ext.dom.Element, no Ext.Component.
Use Ext.getCmp():

```
Ext.getCmp('valueTxt').setValue('new value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Ext.get('valueTxt').set({value: 'hello'});
```